# How to make a gap grow in MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, miglayout

I want to create a vertical list of items with a bottom status line such that when it gets resized, the space between the items and the bottom line grows. Using[MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com) this must be pretty trivial, but somehow it isn't.

The following code does exactly what I want, but I had to use a component to do the spacing:

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap, debug", "[grow, fill]", ""));
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    final JEditorPane line = new JEditorPane();
    line.setText("a" + i);
    panel.add(line);
}
panel.add(new JLabel(), "push"); // This should be a gap!
final JLabel status = new JLabel("status line");
panel.add(status, "");
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I guess I could specify the growing gap in the third constructor argument, but the list length is variable. This could be all solved, too, but I doubt it's the best practice. What I was hoping for, was something like `gaptop push`, but it seems to do nothing at all.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an argument doing what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MigLayout` is a very powerful manager indeed. This could be accomplished
in multiple ways. I provide three solutions.

Solution 1

We put a greedy gap between row 5 and 6.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutGapGrow extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutGapGrow() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Gaps");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


    private void initUI() {


        setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap", "[grow, fill]", "[][][][][]20:push[]"));

        add(new JTextField("a"+1));
        add(new JTextField("a"+2));
        add(new JTextField("a"+3));
        add(new JTextField("a"+4));
        add(new JTextField("a"+5));

        final JLabel status = new JLabel("status line");
        add(status);


        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutGapGrow ex = new MigLayoutGapGrow();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Solution 2

We enlarge the last cell in which the label is placed. The label is then
aligned to the bottom.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutGapGrow2 extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutGapGrow2() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Gaps");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap, debug", "[grow, fill]"));

        add(new JTextField("a"+1));
        add(new JTextField("a"+2));
        add(new JTextField("a"+3));
        add(new JTextField("a"+4));
        add(new JTextField("a"+5));

        final JLabel status = new JLabel("status line");
        add(status, "pushy, bottom");

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutGapGrow2 ex = new MigLayoutGapGrow2();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Solution 3

The label is attached to the bottom using relative positioning. Relative
positioning does not seem to work with the `pack()` method and this might
be a problem.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutGapGrow3 extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutGapGrow3() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Gaps");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap", "[grow, fill]"));

        add(new JTextField("a"+1), "id a1");
        add(new JTextField("a"+2));
        add(new JTextField("a"+3));
        add(new JTextField("a"+4));
        add(new JTextField("a"+5));

        final JLabel status = new JLabel("status line");
        add(status, "pos a1.x visual.y2-p");

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutGapGrow3 ex = new MigLayoutGapGrow3();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Gaps]

Answer (score 0):

If you add push on the component it has a different semnatic. From the [docs](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/cheatsheet.html):

Makes the row and/or column that the component is residing in grow with "weight". This can be used instead of having a "grow" keyword in the column/row constraints.

So you have to add the push keyword as the row constraint.